# How can I echo these functions instead of doing

Tags: php

How can I echo my functions instead of doing it the way that I am doing it. Here is the code;

```
  mysql_connect(db_server, db_user, db_pass);
  $result2 = mysql_db_query(db_name,"SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY user_id ASC LIMIT 5");

  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { 
  if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
      echo "<tr style='padding-top:10px;'>";
      echo "<td>" . $row2['user_id'] . "</td>";  
      echo "<td>" . $row['online'] . "</td>";  
      echo "</tr>";
  }
  }
```

How can I echo my code without the while and if tags set that way?

Comment: you should rephrase your question.

Comment: you are doing with the wrong way, what you want to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
   <?php
   mysql_connect(db_server, db_user, db_pass);
   $result2 = mysql_db_query(db_name,"SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY user_id ASC LIMIT 5");

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { 
     if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
       $userId = $row['user_id'];
       $userOnline = $row['online'];
       ?>
       <tr style='padding-top:10px;'>
       <td><?=$userId?></td>
       <td><?=$userOnline?></td>
       </tr>
       <?php
     }
    }
   ?>
```

I guess I should make the honorable mention: mysql_connect (and the other mysql_ functions) has been depreciated. You should look at transitioning to mysqli or PDO.